# HashMap< HashMap<String,Integer>, Integer > keeping track of sets

Tags: java, hashmap, comparator

I'm generating HashMap and I want to keep track of how many HashMaps of each kind I am generating by putting them in another HashMap< HashMap< String,Integer >, Integer > where the value is the frequency.

My code looks like this:

```
HashMap< HashMap<String,Integer>,Integer> myHashmaps = new HashMap< HashMap<String,Integer> , Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
    HashMap<String, Integer> generatedMap = generateHashMap();
    if(myHashmaps.containsValue(generatedMap)){
         sets.put(generatedMap, myHashmaps.get(generatedMap) + 1 );
    }else{
         myHashmaps.put(generatedMap,1 );
    }
}
```

After the end of the loop, I will print the most frequently occuring hashmap from myHashmaps.

The issue I am having is that generated hashmaps with the same keys and sets are showing up in myHashmaps multiple times. What am I missing?

Comment: Error: `sets` is not defined.

Comment: Also, it appears like you are using a `HashMap` as a key which makes little sense. You sure, you are not looking for `HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String,Integer>>`?

Comment: @Domi sorry about that. just fixed it

Comment: `HashMap< HashMap<String,Integer> , Integer>` - This scares me...

Comment: So I am generating HashMaps and want to see what kind of hashmap I generate most. This is the first abstraction I thought of. Is there another way to keep track of the number of hashmaps I create?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a HashMap as key, you should change :

```
if(myHashmaps.containsValue(generatedMap)){
```

to

```
if(myHashmaps.containsKey(generatedMap)){
```

This still doesn't explain why you see `generated hashmaps with the same keys and sets are showing up in myHashmaps multiple times`. A `HashMap` is equal to another `HashMap` if all their entries are equal, which means all their key/value pairs are equal. Two maps having the exact same keys will still be considered different from each other if the values for each key are not equal. You should check if those Maps which you think are appearing multiple times have the exact same keys and values.

You should also note that if you change any of the inner Maps used as keys in the outer Map, the outer HashMap wouldn't calculate a new bin for that key based on the new value of the `hashCode`, and therefore you may encounter a situation of two identical keys in your outer Map. That's a good reason not to use a HashMap (or any mutable object) as the key of a HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

You are using myHashmaps.containsValue(generatedMap) . What this will do is check whether the hash map contains generatedMap as a Value and not as a Key. This will never be returned as True because all the values will be of Integer type (Eg 1) and this will never be equal to a Hashmap.

Due to this  the if condition is never true which will result in execution of myHashmaps.put(generatedMap,1 ) everytime. Replace containsValue with containsKey.

```
if(myHashmaps.containsKey(generatedMap)){
         sets.put(generatedMap, myHashmaps.get(generatedMap) + 1 );
    }else{
         myHashmaps.put(generatedMap,1 );
    }
```

After this the sets map will contains the hashmaps and their frequency of occurence.